# Can I format Yahoo Link Preview from a website?

Tags: email, hyperlink, yahoo, preview

Yahoo Link Preview is a facility of Yahoo Mail in which one enters a website url on outgoing mail and Yahoo Mail automatically picks up an image from the website and some text and displays this graphically on the body of the outgoing mail.

My question is whether it is possible to include anything on the website (like a meta tag) that would specify the image, text and background color of what Yahoo picks up.  I can't find anything online.

Thanks in advance,

John

Comment: You probably need to check the user agent, and change what you send based on that, eg. If the user agent is whatever Yahoo uses when getting those previews, then serve a different CSS stylesheet.

Comment: It doesn't read stylesheets :)  It reads OpenGraph & Schema.org tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as a matter of fact you can.  Yahoo LinkPreviews reads OpenGraph & Schema.org tags.  So, you can specify meta tags using the OpenGraph spec if you'd like.

Some OpenGraph examples would be og:title, og:image, and og:description.

Here is the spec for OpenGraph:
http://ogp.me

Comment: It also supports the oEmbed (https://oembed.com) spec.  So, if your domain is registered with oEmbed, it will read that info as well.  I believe the order of priority is oEmbed first, then OpenGraph & schema.org, then it falls back to crawling the HTML.  There may be some mixing & matching from these sources as well.